All the sucking up (to the customers)

Why should I share my tips with other waitresses?
I did all the sucking up.

Or is it better to say "I did all the sucking up to the customers"?

With context, the ellipsis is perfectly intelligible.

If you're exploring how to use the phrasal verb "sucking up", waiting at table is hardly the ideal example, as it doesn't necessarily involve being obsequious.  A person serving customers food need not be servile.  Look to politics for better examples.

@TimR While they don't need to be, this waitress apparently feels that they have been, and deserve the reward.

Either way but only among your peers.

@Barmar   It's the definite article that made me think the OP might or might not fully understand what "sucking up" means, especially if in some dictionary or translation service between English and their own language there was some miscommunication involving the word servile.  Also, the very nature of the question  --is "to the customers" necessary? --  gave me that impression, as if the OP thought the phrase might be used only in the serving context and thus "to the customers" might be unnecessary.

What do you mean by "better"?

@Lambie Or superiors — it is a little odd to think of using it for clients/customers, although in some industries (perhaps sales rather than restaurants) one might picture the client as a powerful person whose favour is needed and who can thus be "sucked up to", I think.

@LukeSawczak I said peers, which excludes clients and customers. It could be between waitpersons.

@Lambie Indeed, whereas I'm pushing back on "only peers" — in my opinion it applies if there's something the person can do for you (and I agree that restaurant clientele aren't the most typical example).

Unqualified do all the sucking up is potentially ambiguous, since (at least in principle) you might have been using a shortened version of suck it up and go (stoically endure hardship, as for example the perceived "humiliation" of working in a "service" capacity).

"to the customers" is not needed. Whoever she's talking to knows that she's talking about customers, since they're the ones who give tips, and she thinks that the tips should be considered an individual reward for how well she treated her customers.
